# LOM vs. NIC for iDRAC with Dell PowerEdge R720xd

Tags: networking, dell-poweredge, nic, drac, lom

I'm trying to get going with iDRAC 7 Express (no Enterprise license so we can't use the dedicated port).  In the setup menu for iDRAC, it asks to choose which network interface to use for iDRAC.  There are four choices: LOM1, LOM2, LOM3, and LOM4.  The server has 4 Broadcom NIC ports.  Does NIC1 correspond to LOM1, NIC2 to LOM2, and so on?

What I find slightly puzzling is that, as expected, each individual NIC port has it's own MAC Address.  However in the setup for iDRAC, the MAC Address for iDRAC appears to be static regardless of which LOM I choose.  The only thing that I can think of is that the NIC port is simply "re-directing" the connection to the iDRAC controller, and therefore that static address is for the controller, and not the NIC port.

Currently the machine is getting it's regular connection (not iDRAC) through NIC1, so I assume that I would want to NOT choose LOM1 for iDRAC.

Comment: Lights out Management is for HP Servers. Same thing as IDrac (Inegrated Dell Remote Access Controller) for Dell.

Comment: @stephen. No, [LOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) is a generic term. LOM on HP is called [iLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management). The word LOM can be (and is) used to denote iDRAC ports (see joeqwerty's comments).

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter
iDRAC7 Express does not have a dedicated NIC, you should be able to share other onboard ports.

**Available modes are:**

Dedicated, Shared, Shared with Failover LOM2, and Shared with Failover All LOMs.

You may have issues with iDRAC7 Express if you try to use NIC teaming.

Comment: Nifty options. Dedicated DRAC seems to be the way to go these days.

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: Yeah, I've read about those options.  In the iDRAC7 setup it doesn't list those terms exactly, it just says basically "choose which LOM to use," so I'm mostly just trying to determine if LOM1 == NIC1, LOM2 == NIC2, etc.

Comment: Yes. LOM1 = NIC1, etc. LOM = Lan On Motherboard, meaning the integrated NIC as opposed to the dedicated iDRAC port available with the Enterprise license.

Comment: Interesting, I was reading around and the definition of LOM I kept coming across was "Lights out management."

Comment: not on Dell iDrac.

Comment: In some contexts LOM is used to mean Lights Out Management, but in the context of the iDRAC it means Lan On Motherboard.

Comment: So I finally got this sorted out through a lot of trial and error.  For starters, the iDRAC 7 Configuration Utility does NOT have "modes" such as dedicated, shared, shared with failover LOM2, and so on.  These were the options in iDRAC 6 and perhaps earlier.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt I'm trying to get a new server with basic iDRAC 7 working.  In the BIOS config, LOM4 is selected and I have a ethernet cable plugged into NIC4.   Can't ping or otherwise reach the DRAC.   What other settings do I need to look at?